# What is cost/benefit of object.models.find() vs Model.find() in Ruby on Rails (Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've seen code where instead of just calling `Model.find(m_id)` the code is using the fact that a model `belongs_to` some other object and form the call this way: `object.models.find(m_id)`. If one already has the primary key, and especially if that primary key is indexed, it seems to be a bit redundant (and perhaps a bit more expensive) to use the "Model belongs_to object" relationship.

The only thing that comes to mind is that by limiting the collection the find operates upon has a security value but that seems a little tenuous. So, why would someone opt to use `object.models.find(m_id)` when one could just call `Model.find(m_id)`?

Comment: I don't think the overhead will be too great, it just adds an additional where clause to your query, to scope it to the ID of the related object. See answer by mechninov.

Comment: Thanks @bo-oz, that's more in line with what I was seeking. So, it's more likely to be a more qualified query than two queries, which is good.

Comment: ActiveRecord is quite optimized, so it would surprise me if there’s really a lot of costs, I think it wouldn’t actually fetch the record for object if it’s not necessary, but I’d definitely advise to benchmark. A lot of people use it because scoping through the parent adds sort of a security that you’ll never do actions on a record that does not ‘belong’ to the parent.

Comment: FYI, while I didn't state this explicitly in the text, I did tag this as MongoDB and Mongoid. However, I think the same assertion regarding it being optimized still holds true.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Model.find(m_id)` you simply find model by its primary key.

When you use `object.models.find(m_id)` you find model in object's collection by primary key.

For example, you have:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And you have:

```
#<Message id: 1, user_id: 1>
```

Now if you call `Message.find(1)` you will get that message.

But when you call `User.find(2).messages.find(1)` you get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

Because user #1 has this message but user #2 hasn't.

Comment: Not to be overly critical but in my opinion you just detailed what I described in "by limiting the collection the find operates upon...".  I suppose my query was not clear enough but I was hoping for more of a cost/benefit analysis as indicated in the title. The benefit is limiting the scope of the find but it seems one would endure additional cost. If a query is coming from the UI to modify message with id: 1, is the benefit there to justify the cost?

Comment: It only depends on your objective. If you want just modify message #1, of course use `Message.find(1)`. If you want to modify message #1 and check if user #1 has it so use `User.find(1).messages.find(1)`.